# Customize vuetify variables - why @import must be at the end of variables.scss file?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I have a project made by vue cli and I want to change vuetify's default variables, e.g the $red color to another color,
Following vuetify docs, to do this I can have a file named `variables.scss` in `src/sass` directory.
In the `variables.scss` file, ​vuetify style file must be imported. but if I import it first, it does not work:

```
first import:
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles'

then custom vars:
.... start custom variables

for example:
$red: (
'base': #fd2ff0
)

.... end custom variables
```

But when I set @import at the end of the file
, it works well:

```
first custom vars:
.... start custom variables

for example:
$red: (
'base': #fd2ff0
)

.... end custom variables

then import:
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles'
```

Why this happens?

doesn't scss files apply line by line?
So why the style that I have set at the top, overrides the styles at the bottom?

I think this is upside down!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always...[docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables) can help:

> Sass variables are *imperative*, which means if you use a variable and then change its value, the earlier use will stay the same. CSS variables are *declarative*, which means if you change the value, it’ll affect both earlier uses and later uses.

So if you import Vuetify scss with all variable declarations **and** CSS using them, that CSS will not be affected by the overriding variable declaration done after the import...

Also, Vuetify declares all it's variables with `!default` [which means](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables#default-values) that values provided by Vuetify will be applied **only** if not declared before...

Combine the two and it is clear that to override any build-in Vuetify variable you must declare it 1st and import Vuetify styles later